# protection method that you need to know exact 3 or more ports to access network

Tags: networking, network-access, port-security

long time ago i found an wiki article for method that protect your network from unwanted access.
method was something like:
attacker need to know 2, 3 or more exact ports which are open to access the network.
in the case of 3 ports, one of them can be closed at certain time "port1", and other two can be open, after a time "port1" opens and "port3" closes, so in that way it confuses port scanners

i forgot how this method was called so i can find the article and find information how to do it my self.

i remember that this was some kind of methot that network admins protect their network.

Can someone help me, telling me what was the name of that method or give me some articles about this type of protection or something similar?

Comment: You should ask this question on [security.se].

Comment: Are you referring to Port Knocking, maybe?

Comment: Also, just use a firewall that blocks all the TCP and UDP ports. People scan my address all the time, but they find all ports closed, and it looks like there is nothing connected at my address. Something like the Shields UP test at GRC always shows that there does not appear to be anything at my address.

Comment: @JesseP. Yea. This  is i was looking for. Thanx allot!

Comment: @RonMaupin That looks interesting. I will try to find some information about this

Comment: @RonMaupin Are you saying you don’t have any ports externally accessible, even for your own access? Or are you saying you have them locked down to just your public IP address(es) so everyone else sees them as closed?

Comment: @JesseP., no, just that the firewall does not respond in any way to unknown traffic (probes). It appears that there is nothing at my address for people looking for a host to compromise.

Comment: @RonMaupin So you have exclusions for your known addresses to get through but deny statements for everything else.

Comment: @JesseP., simplistically, yes, but it is really more complicated than that. There are ways to access from unknown addresses, but it requires some special knowledge to get access though the firewall. The firewall itself cannot be accessed from outside.

Comment: @RonMaupin That wasn’t vague at all. :)

Comment: @RonMaupin Could you share some knowledge about the subject you are talking about ?

Comment: @JesseP., not on an open site.

Comment: @RonMaupin That’s fair

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer i was looking for is posted in comment by @Jesse P.

The method is called Port Knocking

Comment: You should note that port knocking isn't regarded as providing sufficient security any more. Today's Internet is extremely hostile. There are port scanning techniques that try to find the opening mechanism. For decent security, you should either limit port forwarding to known source addresses (or ranges) or - much better - use proper VPN.

Comment: @Zac67 Ou.. Interesting
Im new at this.
Could you share some resources regarding network security that are viable today and working for todays standards ( not outdated )

Comment: Sorry, such requests for resources are explicitly off-topic here (to avert spam attempts). But generally, services open to the Internet require either explicit (code and configuration) hardening or a very elaborate application-level filtering (ALG) plus decent firewalling and possibly IDS and IPS. Port knocking is attempting "security by obscurity" which doesn't work reliably.